# Change CKEditor autoGrow_maxHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Can I change CKEditor's autoGrow_maxHeight at runtime (jquery or etc)? I've tried

```
CKEDITOR.replace ('editor1', { autoGrow_maxHeight: x });
```

And also destroying the instance before trying to recreate it, with a new maxHeight.

I'm trying to keep the maxHeight to the height of the browser window (minus about 220 px of other stuff on the page). This is when I do the main replace of the text area:

```
autoGrow_maxHeight: (window.innerHeight-220)
```

This works for the initial creation of the editor. But the problem is when you resize the browser window - I have no way of saying 'redetermine that autogrow height please'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, once defined, this property's value will last until CKEditor instance is destroyed. So to set a different value you got to [destroy your editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy) and [re-create](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load) it. Another possibility is to modify plugin's code to match your needs. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, looking at the [autogrow plugin code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/autogrow/plugin.js) I think that it may be possible to modify the values by `editor.config.*`. But it needs tests to see if it works correctly.